# How to position my link(button) in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to position my button in the middle. I tried using

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

but nothing happens. Code is below:

[Why does margin: 0 auto; doesnt work?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r9Mg.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    margin: 0 auto;  <!--Why margin: 0 auto; doesnt work?  -->
}
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}


a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. The margin `0 auto` was not working because your div was using 100% of the body width. once you set it to be less than 100%, it automatically adjusts.

```css
body, html{
  width: 99%;  
}

div {
    margin: 0 auto;  
    width: 134px;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}


a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

edited the snippet

Comment: How does your solution centers the button? Now you can scroll sideways and there is more white space left.

Comment: edited the snipped. how it centers is already explained above.